# Inheritance when specializing a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class myClass{
    public:
        double Foo(double x){return x;}
}

template<>
class myClass<SpecialType>{
    public:
        double Bar(double x){return x+1.0;}
}
```

Now, I'd like to instantiate the specialization, but still have access to the method `Foo` without re-writing the whole thing in the specialization, i.e.:

```
myClass<SpecialType> A;
double y = A.Foo(1.0);
```

Is there a way to do this with my current setup, or do I need to write a "master" class in order to inherit `Foo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options (out of several more):

- Construct a common base class in which you put all type-independent stuff (recommended):

  ```
  struct myClassBase
  {
      virtual double Foo(double x) const {return x+1.0;}
  };

  template<typename T> struct myClass : public myClassBase
  {
       //...
  };

  template<>
  struct myClass<SpecialType> : public myClassBase
  {
      double Bar(double x){return x+1.0;}
  }
  ```

  That is recommended particularly when your functions do not depend on the template parameter.
- Derive from your non-specialized class:

  ```
  template<>
  struct myClass<SpecialType> : public myClass</* be careful what to write here */>
  {
      double Bar(double x){return x+1.0;}
  }
  ```

  You have to be careful, though, which type you pass to the non-specialized class template (particularly when your member function depend on the template type -- which they somehow should in order to make sense).
- Another more static option would be to apply the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern): Transfer all functionality to some small strategy classes, then build your required classes via composition of those (disadvantage: you have to expose the functions again), or via multiple inheritance (here you do not have to restate the whole thing, but be careful again on avoiding ambiguities).

---

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, here is the CRTP approach to the same task:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct myClassBase
{
    double Foo(double x) const
    {
        return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).specialMember(x);
    }
    //all other stuff independent of the derived class specialization

    //possibly define specialMember once:
    virtual double specialMember(double x) const { return x; }
}

template<typename T> struct myClass : public myClassBase<myClass<T> >
{
    //... special member of Base class is sufficient
};

template<> struct myClass<SpecialType> : public myClassBase<myClass<SpecialType> >
{
    virtual double specialMember(double x) const { return x+1.0; }
};
```

**Again, note that this does only make sense when the template types are really involved in the evaluation of the function.**

On the other hand, if overloading on `double Foo(double x)` is sufficient, forget the whole template stuff and use the first alternative.

Comment: In the second paradigm:  suppose I have some (base) class member functions that use *specialized* member functions, but in a generic way?  I.e. I have something like `Foo(double x){return SpecialFun(x);}`, where `SpecialFun(x)` is defined in every specialization, but in a different way? In other words, only the specializations depend on the template parameter, but I want generic code which works for each specialization.  This is probably the wrong approach...?

Comment: That sounds like CRTP is another way to go for you. I'll make an edit. (but whether it is really such depends on your requirements, which are not completely clear to me ... maybe you make another edit in your question, or append something new?)

Comment: OK, I thought about it a little harder, and I realized I was being thick.  The CRTP approach could work, but was overly complictated for what I needed, since the dependence only went one way.  All I needed to do was write a separate helper class, templated on the specialization type of `myClass`.  Your suggestion helped me work it out though.

Answer (score 1):

You may *repeat* the common part in specialization

```
template<typename T>
class myClass
{
public:
    double Foo(double x){return x;}
};

template<>
class myClass<SpecialType>
{
public:
    double Foo(double x){return x;}
    double Bar(double x){return x + 1.0;}
};
```

or using other helper class as:

```
template<typename T> struct BarHelper<T> {};
template<> struct BarHelper<SpecialType>
{
    double Bar(double x) {return x + 1.0;}
};

template<typename T>
class myClass : public BarHelper<T>
{
public:
    double Foo(double x){return x;}
    // inherit Bar method for SpecialType.
};
```